# Bootstrap columns not working with width adjustment

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to display two input areas next to each other with one taking less space than the other. This is what I have now but somehow it won't work.

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 fitContent col-xs-8">
            <span class="input-group-text">Reihentitel</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputReihentitel" input>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 fitContent col-xs-4">
            <span class="input-group-text">Bandaufführung</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBandaufführung" input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I just use the .col class it splits the two div tags evenly across the screen. With for example the .col-xs-8 and .col-xs-4 it is displayed one below the other.

Now I put the input-group into an other div which has the .col class but it is the same as before.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text">Reihentitel</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputReihentitel" input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text">Bandaufführung</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBandaufführung" input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't mix classes in bootstrap when it comes to row and col. Nest your input-group inside the col class with another div.

Comment: @cloned I tried it as you said but it still won't work. I put the code in my Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [read the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#grid-options) you will see that the smallest columns don't need any prefixes anymore. This is because this is the default width and you don't need any prefixes for a default.

In other words: `col-xs-4` becomes just `col-4` (since it is 4-width on all sizes, not only xs)

My advice from the comments to not mix column-classes with other classes is still something I highly recommend. It is too easy to just overwrite column styling and have the layout break if you do it otherwise.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text">Reihentitel</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputReihentitel" input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text">Bandaufführung</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBandaufführung" input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```